# 2 parameters invoke lambda aws from golang

Tags: go, aws-lambda

i want to send the 2 parameters a lambda needs in order to work and it basically needs the value i want to search and as a second parameter the field where to find that value.

Now with no problem i've been able to access some other lambdas with that only need one parameter with a code like this.

```
func (s *resourceService) GetProject(ctx context.Context, name string) projectStruct {

    payload, err := json.Marshal(name)

    util.Logger.Debugf("Payload",payload)
    invokeOutput, err := s.lambdaSvc.Invoke(ctx, &lambda.InvokeInput{
        FunctionName:   &s.getProject,
        InvocationType: "RequestResponse",
        Payload: payload,

    })
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    var project projectStruct
    err = json.Unmarshal(invokeOutput.Payload, &project)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    util.Logger.Debugf("Invocation output [%v]", invokeOutput)
    return project
}
```

now with 2 parameters i've had a lot of problems and tried a LOT of different approaches starting for adding another Payload value, creating a string with the 2 values and marshal it, marshaling both parameters and try and add them as the payload, even append both marshaled bytes array but i've been incapable of sending 2 parameters as the payload

Do you know the right way to do so? Please Help

Answer (score 0):

Lambda functions only take one Payload.  In [V1 of the AWS SDK, InvokeInput](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/lambda#InvokeInput) takes *one* `[]byte` parameter expressing JSON, as you already know.

You can structure your *one* Json Payload to carry a *list*.  Looking at your example, Payload could look something like

```
["name","name"]
```

You could change your signature like so:

```
func (s *resourceService) GetProject(ctx context.Context, names []string) projectStruct
```

`json.Marshal` can handle marshaling a slice just as well as the elements within the slice, so the remaining code doesn't need to change.

Of course the *receiving* function must *agree* about the schema of the data it's being passed.   If you wish to change from a string to a *list* of strings, that will be a breaking change.  For that reason, Json schemas typically use *named* values instead of scalars.

```
[{ "Name": "Joan"},{"Name":"Susan"}]
```

You can add `Age` and `Address` without breaking the receiving function (though of course, it will ignore the new fields until you program it to ignore them).

Take time to [Get to know JSON](https://towardsdatascience.com/an-introduction-to-json-c9acb464f43e) - it's a simple and expressive encoding standard that is reliably supported everywhere.   JSON is a natural choice for encoding structured data in Go because [JSON integrates well with Go's with structures, maps, and slices](https://go.dev/blog/json).

Comment: Thank you  for the the help, having that in mind i think i'm going to use an object as an input an change the lambda parameter to work with it